# What is the syntax of a comment in a .rgs file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, registry, atl, rgs

For reasons which I won't go into I am auto-generating a load of .rgs files for a Visual Studio 2008 ATL project. I would like to be able to put a comment into each .rgs file indicating that it was auto-generated, and when, but I can't find out what the comment syntax for a .rgs file is, if indeed there is one. I've tried // ; ;; REM and even # but none of these works. There seems to be a paucity of documentation available for the .rgs file format. Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no comments on registrar scripts. See [Creating Registrar Scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8350a3tf) on MSDN for details.

If you are interested in internals, take a look at `$(VisualStudio)\VC\atlmfc\include\statreg.h` implementation.